# Cannot resolve method addServlet, addListener //Spring MVC

Tags: spring

Пытался перевести конфигурацию приложения в java-классы и столкнулся с такой проблемой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы что-то не то делаете, зачем Вы руками подымаете спринговый контекст?

Когда я делал конфиг полностью на аннотациях, я делал так:

```
package configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.*;


public class MyAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{MvcContext.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class}; //тут можно подсунуть файлы с конфигами основных частей приложения
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
```

}

код до безобразия прост, думаю в пояснениях не нуждается.

А по существу вопроса: ну нет в интерфейсе ServletContext таких методов, которые Вы пытаетесь вызвать.

Comment: Спасибо что ответили, у меня все так же как у вас в проекте, но мне нужно добавить фильтр. Я уже много всего пересмотрел и все на ServletContext вызывают методы add, может это какой-то другой ServletContext? К примеру вот: 
[ссылка](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javax.servlet.ServletContext&method=addFilter)

Comment: @mctraher777, хм ... а какая версия библиотеки javax.servlet-api.jar?

Comment: 3.1.0, но я пробовал и другие версии, тоже самое

Comment: @mctraher777, надо код тогда комплексно смотреть ... по скриншоту сложно угадать, что у Вас там происходит

Comment: [git-hub](https://github.com/vladdaviduk/english-test-local) посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @mctraher777, посмотрел. Проблема в зависимостях. У Вас google-oauth-client-jetty тащит за собой реализацию servlet-api версии 2.5. Добавьте exclusion в зависимость 

              <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>